# Export a contact to the iphone address book?

Tags: ios, export, addressbook

I want to export a contact with info from my app to the address book of the user, how can I do this?

I`ve seen answers of the opposite, getting address book into the app but nothing about what I need.

thanks

Comment: Use the `ABAddressBook` framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ABAddressBook` framework is what you're looking for.

Documentation is available from Apple here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABAddressBookRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html